# Erro ao Ler um arquivo e executar linha a linha no nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript

Boa tarde,
Estou criando um código para ler uma arquivo texto e executar linha a linha utilizando os pacotes execa e listr no nodejs, porem ele esta fazendo o check da função task primeiro depois executa os comandos.
Codigo ta assim:

```
async function print(file_path, callback) {
  fs.readFileSync(file_path.toString() , 'utf8', function(err, texto) {
    if (err){
      return callback (err);
    }else {
      var linhas = texto.split(/\rs?\n/);
      linhas.forEach(function(linha){
        const pRetry = require('p-retry');
          const run = async () => {
            const results = await execa(linha);
            return results;
          };
          (async () => {
            console.log(pRetry(run, {retries: 5}));
          })();
      });
    }
  })
}
const tasks = new Listr([
    {
      title: chalk.green('Criação de diretorios'),
      task: () => print('teste.txt',function(texto,err){
        if (err) {
          throw new Error('Deve ser executado com root')
        }
      })
    },
```

]);
tasks.run().catch((err: any) => {
process.exit();
});

saida esta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se ele está mostrando `Promise { <pending> }` é pq tem algo async que vc não está tratando.

Comment: Ao invés de `console.log(pRetry(run, {retries: 5}));` se fizer

```js
const result = await run ();
console.log(pRetry(result, { retries: 5 }))

```

Comment: fiz a alteração que vc falou e não aparece mais o Promise {<pending>} , porem na execução das task ele ja da o ckeck em todas as task como feita e vai executando em segundo plano..  queria que ele executasse uma task e so depois que terminar chamar a proxima task.

Comment: https://oieduardorabelo.medium.com/javascript-armadilhas-do-asyn-await-em-loops-1cdad44db7f0

Esse artigo vai responder o problema que você está tendo. Que é ter a parte async dentro de um loop. Ele explica como deixar sequencial respeitando a ordem do array.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde;
Consegui resolver o meu problema, o que estava acontecendo é que eu estava passando o execa junto com a função, e que na verdade tinha que colocar o execa dentro do listr.. segue o exemplo abaixo.

```
function print(file_path: string) {
  try {
    const data = fs.readFileSync(file_path.toString(), "utf8");
    var linhas = data.split(/\r?\n/);
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}


const task = new Listr([
  {
    title: chalk.green('Criação dos diretorios'),
    task: () => execSync(print('c:/teste.txt'))
  },
]);
```